# Write cleaner code for a dynamic object definition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash, axios

I'm using vue and trying to achieve a dynamic axios GET query which will be generated dynamically, based on what is filled in the search form. Right now I have this method in a single file component:

UPDATE:

```
<template lang="pug">
    div
        form(@submit.prevent="search")
            input(type='text', name="user_seq_id", placeholder="Customer ID")
            input(type='text', name="registered", placeholder="Registration date")
            input(type='text', name="email", placeholder="E-Mail")
            input(type='text', name="organization", placeholder="Organization")
            input(type='text', name="firstname", placeholder="Firstname")
            input(type='text', name="lastname", placeholder="Lastname")
            button(type="submit") Submit
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods: {
            search(e) {
                let user_seq_id = e.target.elements.user_seq_id.value,
                    registered = e.target.elements.registered.value,
                    email = e.target.elements.email.value,
                    organization = e.target.elements.organization.value,
                    firstname = e.target.elements.firstname.value,
                    lastname = e.target.elements.lastname.value,
                    params = {
                        filter: 'role',
                        role: 'User',
                        sort: 'registered|desc'
                    }

                if ( user_seq_id ) {
                    _.set(params, 'user_seq_id', user_seq_id)
                    params.filter = params.filter + ',user_seq_id'
                }
                if ( registered ) {
                    _.set(params, 'registered', registered)
                    params.filter = params.filter + ',registered'
                }
                if ( email ) {
                    _.set(params, 'email', email)
                    params.filter = params.filter + ',email'
                }
                if ( organization ) {
                    _.set(params, 'organization', organization)
                    params.filter = params.filter + ',organization'
                }
                if ( firstname ) {
                    _.set(params, 'firstname', firstname)
                    params.filter = params.filter + ',firstname'
                }
                if ( lastname ) {
                    _.set(params, 'lastname', lastname)
                    params.filter = params.filter + ',lastname'
                }

                this.$store.commit('users', null)

                return this.$axios.get('/users', {
                        params: {
                            filter: 'role',
                            role: 'User',
                            sort: 'registered|desc'
                        }
                    })
                    .then( ({ data, headers, request, status, statusText }) => {
                        return this.$store.commit('users', data.result)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Anyone here who knows to simplify this somehow? I find it very dump to repeat myself everytime and I'm sure there's a better way to do this. As you can see, I'm using "lodash" to inject properties to the "param" Object.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: sample of e.targets.elements?

Comment: it is essential to add params .filter?

Comment: I updated the code to verify things a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just just want the refactoration of the code I am not considering the logic you are using to set the `params`.

You can try this:

```
methods:{
   search(e) {

        let data = {
            user_seq_id: e.target.elements.user_seq_id.value,
            registered: e.target.elements.registered.value,
            email: e.target.elements.email.value,
            organization: e.target.elements.organization.value,
            firstname: e.target.elements.firstname.value,
            lastname: e.target.elements.lastname.value
       };

       let params = {
                filter: 'role',
                role: 'User',
                sort: 'registered|desc'
          };

    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
        if(data[key]){
            this.modifyParams(params, key, data[key]);
        }
    });


        this.$store.commit('users', null)

        this.$axios.get('/users', {
            params: params
        })
        .then( ({ data, headers, request, status, statusText }) => {
            return this.$store.commit('users', data.result)
        })

    },
     modifyParams(obj, key, value){
        _.set(obj, key, value)
            obj.filter = obj.filter + ',' + key;
    }


}
```

PS: Since in JavaScript the objects are passed by reference the original `params` object will only be modified

Comment: I updated the code, although I don't know, how it helps to clean it up?! The params are used to help mongoDB to query in the database. The params string will be used to dynamically build up the find()-Object later on in my api.

Comment: But thanks for your suggestion. At least it helps to set it more dynamically :)

Comment: @PatrickDahm you didnt want your code to repeat. So i refactored the code to look more lean.